# SQL view with "with check option" but also with "join"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello i try make view like in this code:
`

```
CREATE VIEW Empsandbosses as
select  e1.surname  || ' ' || e1.name as employee
        , e2.surname || ' ' || e2.name as boss 
from employees e1 
inner join employees e2 on e1.boss_id=e2.emp_id
where e1.salary < e2.salary;`
```

each employees (this also includes bosses) have own id and boss_id in the same table so i I had to join them, now i must modify it and add "with check option". I've been trying for several hours with subqueries, "case" and "with" but i get errors "ERROR: WITH CHECKING OPTION is only available in automatically updating views
TIP: Views that are data retrieved from one table or display are not automatically modifiable." or it not work. I know i cant use "join" but i dont have more idea how do it.
The "best" thing i invented:

```
create view testY as
select name as emp_name
       , (select e2.name as boss_name 
          from employees e1 
          join employees e2 on e1.boss_id=e2.emp_id
          where e1.salary < e2.salary)
from employees 
with check option;
```

but it is useless coz check option does not work on condition to display only cases that the employee earns less than employee's boss.
Is it any way to make it without "join" or use "with check option" with "join"?

Comment: You cannot do what you want.  You want the view to contain information from different rows and that is just not updatable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In PostgreSQL, a view can be updatable when the defining query of the view must have exactly one entry in the FROM clause.

This is not the case in your query since you are trying to join two tables. You should rethink the solution to the problem, or even better, explain what do you want to achieve with this.